# Action of differential on differential operator

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

As I taking the course differential geometry and learning the idea of differential of smooth maps, my professor mentioned the following example:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^+\times \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be given by $f(r,\theta)=(r\cos \theta,r\sin\theta)$, and let $\partial_r,\partial_\theta$ denote differentiation with respect to $r,\theta$ and $\partial_1,\partial_2$ denote differentiation with respect to $x_1,x_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then he says if we use $df_{(r,\theta)}$ to denote the differential of $f$, then
$$
df_{(r,\theta)}(\partial_r)=\cos\theta\partial_1+\sin\theta\partial_2,
$$
and
$$
df_{r,\theta}(\partial_\theta)=-r\sin\theta\partial_1+r\cos\theta\partial_2.
$$
So I get super confused here. Why is the input of the differential of $f$ $\partial_r$ and $\partial_\theta$ here? What is he doing? Shouldn't the input of the differential $df_{(r,\theta)}$ be some tangent vector in the tangent space of $\mathbb{R}^+\times \mathbb{R}$ at some point $(r,\theta)$ as a manifold?

Comment: In differential geometry, the partials $\partial_r$ and $\partial_\theta$ *are* the tangent vectors. How did your class define the tangent space of a smooth manifold if you've never seen this notation before?

Comment: @ EuYu We defined the tangent vectors to be the tangent vector along a certain curve, i.e. let $t\mapsto (a_1(t),a_2(t))\in \mathbb{R}^+\times \mathbb{R}$ be a curve passing a point $(r,\theta)=(a_1(0),a_2(0))$, then the tangent vector at $(r,\theta)$ is just $(\frac{da_1}{dt}, \frac{da_2}{dt})$.

Comment: By writing tangent vectors in terms of their two components, you have implicitly chosen a basis for the tangent space corresponding to the coordinates $(r,\theta)$. $(\partial_r,\partial_\theta)$ are just the conventional names for the elements of that basis.